# Store element in a set with two possible index

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I need a solution for a specific situation. I have an algorithm which basically works on line segments. I only know the line segments end and start points. (Points have 2 coordinates x,y. These are pixel points on image. Also I know the sizes of image.) I want to examine these line segments and do something on them. However, I also need to keep track of examined line segments so that, I wont examine the same line segment again. I'm using C++, so I want to use stl set container.

My question is how can I store these line segments according to their end and start points? I need to produce unique number for end and start points. (Also I'm open for any other advice other than using stl set :))

One possible solution is that I produced index numbers for these two pixels by: (y*image->Witdh) + x. Then I get two index numbers (by the way they are integers.) Then I concatenate these numbers by: (indexStart << 32) + indexEnd.(I get double). Now I have unique number and I can easily store in set. BUT the problem is while on my search, once a start point of a line segment can be the end point of the same line segment. If I came across the same line segment from endpoint then the concatenated line segments unique number become (indexEnd << 32) + indexStart. Then I will add the same line segment to the my set container which I need to avoid.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: you didn't tell what your're going to to with the segments. But you might want to consider a specialized tree like the segment tree for your work (explanation: http://wwwisg.cs.uni-magdeburg.de/ag/lehre/SS2009/GDS/slides/S11.pdf or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep your solution or use an `operator<`. Your has the advantage that switching to some hashset implementation is trivial, the other one should be better practice overall (much easier to understand, probably faster, can be used with 64bit coordinates, etc).

Just solve the problem you describe (you'll have to do this for both apporaches) by not distinguishing`start` and `end` but `lower` and `upper` coordinates. Always using the smaller coordinate in the same place is an easy fix to getting false-positive different segments when you discover them the other way round

Comment: Thank you so much. By making startIndex = min(index1, index2) and endIndex = max(index1, index2), and storing according to their start number solved my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just specify a proper order relation operator for your line segments. I.e. if your segments look like this:

```
struct LineSegment {
  int start;
  int end;
};
```

Simply define `operator<` on that struct, such that there exists an instantiation of `std::less<LineSegment>` (see the [definition of set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) for why this is important).

```
bool operator<(LineSegment const& lhs, LineSegment const& rhs) {
  if (lhs.start == rhs.start)
    return lhs.end < rhs.end;
  return lhs.start < rhs.start;
}
```

This allows you to use `std::set<LineSegment>` sets, which respect proper ordering. LineSegments are guaranteed to be distinct, if and only if they are actually different (if I understood your question correctly, this is just what you want, otherwise, you can easily adapt the `operator<` implementation).

Similarly you can override the comparison operator of your set in the second template parameter (replacing `std::less<LineSegment*>`), if you want to store `LineSegment*` pointers in your set.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is :

```
    (indexLeft << 32) + indexRight
```

But you should assign Left and Right each time. For example, Left is the one has min X value.

Answer (score 0):

One construct that immediately comes to mind is a `set` of `pair`s of `pair`s of `int`s:

`std::set<std::pair<std::pair<int, int>, std::pair<int, int> > >`

This way each key has a definitively unique value and describes a complete line segment.